# Why is "symmetry" in Gaussian quadrature over a triangle a beneficial feature?

Tags: numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$, $\Delta\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be the triangle spanned by $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and $$\mathbb P_r(\Delta):=\left\{p:\Delta\to\mathbb R\mid p(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\le r}\lambda_\alpha x^\alpha\text{ for all }x\in\Delta\text{ for some }(\lambda_\alpha)_{|\alpha|\le r}\subseteq\mathbb R\right\}$$ for some $r\in\mathbb N_0$. Using the approach $$\int_\Delta f\:{\rm d}\lambda\approx\frac12\sum_{i=1}^nw_if(x_i)\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal L^1\left(\left.\lambda\right|_\Delta\right)\;,\tag1$$ with $n\in\mathbb N$, $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in\mathbb R$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Delta$ to be determined, we're able to find a quadrature rule which is exact for all $f\in\mathbb P_r(\Delta)$.

> If, for example, $r=2$, we're able to find a solution (i.e. a choice for $n$, $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$) with $n=2$ (there are $6$ equations and $6$ unknowns). However, I've read that, in practice, a solution with $n=3$ is preferred (such a solution is not unique, since there are $6$ equations and $9$ unknowns).
>
> In those readings, they say that the reason for that is that, with $n=3$, the obtained solutions are "symmetric".
>
> About which kind of "symmetry" are they talking and why is it a beneficial feature?

Comment: Symmetric probably means invariance with respect to transformations (rotations, reflections, etc) in the symmetry group of the element.  My guess (again) is the benefit is to avoid crowding of quadrature points which would degrade accuracy. I would suggest searching on " symmetric quadrature rules for triangular elements" or something similar.

Comment: @RRL If I got you right, you say that the benefit is a better error estimate (for a suitable class of functions); while both approaches are exact for $\mathbb P_r(\Delta)$-functions. Right?