# Using quadrature for the computation of integrals occuring in the finite element method

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, finite-element-method

I want to solve the Navier-Stokes equations numerically. After choosing a temporal discretization scheme and a finite element for the space discretizaion, I need to deal with a system of linear equations.

Suppose we're using Taylor-Hood finite elements $\mathbb P_2/\mathbb P_1$, i.e. the finite elements on which the velocity approximation is searched consists of piecewise quadratic polynomials.

One of the constituents of the coefficient matrix of the linear system involves integrals of the form $$\int_\Lambda(u^0\cdot\nabla\psi_i)\psi_j\:{\rm d}\lambda$$ where $u^0$ is the velocity approximation from the last time step and the $\psi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are two of the local degrees of freedom (which are quadratic polynomials here) of the reference element, which I have chosen to be the triangle $\Delta$ spanned by $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

> The presence of $u^0$ forces me to use quadrature for the approximation of the integral. Suppose we're using [Gaussian quadrature as described in my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200409/why-is-symmetry-in-gaussian-quadrature-over-a-triangle-a-beneficial-feature).
>
> $u^0$ contains the values of the velocity approximation from the last time step at the nodes of the finite element space. Using quadratic Lagrange elements, the local nodes are the vertices of the triangles together with the midpoints of the edges.
>   Now, if I want to use quadrature, didn't I need to choose the sampling points to be precisely the local nodes of the reference element?

Moreover, I would like to now if there is anything else I need to take care of.

Comment: In these sorts of large scale computing problems you're better off using extrapolation methods where you start with large mesh sizes. Often rational function interpolation yield better results than polynomial functions . So, I would not consider using methods such as Gaussian quadrature, such methods are good for getting to arbitrary precision. So, if the question is how to get to a 1000 decimal answer in the fasted way, your led to such methods. But if you want to do to fluid dynamics simulations in an efficient way, you need to consider different methods.

Comment: @CountIblis For the moment, I want to simulate the fluid in a rectangle $(0,a)\times(0,b)$. Do your thoughts still apply to this specific case? If so, do you have a reference for an better approach (e.g. one of the extrapolation methods you mention) in the context of fluid dynamics? (And just to clarify my goal: I plan to animate the fluid in real-time. So an efficient computation is very important for me.)

Comment: @CountIblis Oh, and what do you say to my considerations? I only know $u^0$ at the mentioned sample points. So, I cannot use a quadrature rule which evaluates this function at any other point.